# How to query hstore tag keys that match part of the filter string

Tags: postgresql, hstore

In PostgreSQL query, how can I filter the results by using any record that tags with a key like `%building%`

something like:

```
..
where 
    Table.tags ? '%building%'
```

I didn't find an answer within the postgresql documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/hstore.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a set of the keys in order to be able to compare them using like.

Something like:

```
select *
from the_table t
where exists (select * 
              from skeys(t.tags) as x(tagname)
              where x.tagname like '%building%');
```

But this is not going to be fast.